# Android switching from ProgressDialog to ProgressBar, best implementation with many activities?

Tags: android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-progressbar

The majority of my activities make an async call to an API as they open to retrieve the data which will be displayed. With ProgressDialog, I can simply pass the context of the activity to my AsyncTask class and display/hide the loading circle as this happens. This is useful as it requires no extra work when adding a new activity that will make an async call.

E.g in onPreExecute():

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(contextRef.get());
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
progressDialog.show();
```

I'd like to make the switch to ProgressBar however this requires adding a ProgressBar to the XML of every activity that will require one. The best i've come up with is copy/pasting the XML to every activity and doing something like this in onPreExecute():

```
progressBar = ((Activity) contextRef.get()).findViewById(R.id.loading);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This works fine however the ProgressBar is a relatively big chunk of XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingTop="250dp"
    android:paddingBottom="250dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I'm not a fan of this as if I need to change something I would have to change it everywhere. Is there a way to put the ProgressBar in a layout file and have the other layouts reference this? Or just a better way to go about this in general?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use this library: `https://github.com/FANMixco/spots-dialog`

```
private SpotsDialog progressDialog;
```

and

```
            progressDialog = (SpotsDialog) new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(activity)
                .setMessage("One moment please ...")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .build();
        progressDialog.show();
```

I also use it in asynctask, it's easy to swap for progressdialog and works great.

When you use proguard do not forget

```
-keep class dmax.dialog.** { *;}
```

Otherwise the points are not displayed